# Will there be an incompatibility issue with trying to run a 32bit Windows 7 OS on a 64bit cpu/motherboard?

Tags: windows, 32-vs-64-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a 32 bit OS run in a 64 bit processor?](https://superuser.com/questions/9083/can-a-32-bit-os-run-in-a-64-bit-processor)

Is it possible to connect an HDD with a 32bit Windows 7 OS to run on a Z77 motherboard with corei7 3770K processor.  Or will I need a 64bit OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you do not need a 64bit OS. A 32bit OS can run on 64bit hardware with no problem. You just won't get any advantages from your 64bit hardware.